# Error Parsing JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a string like this:

```
{

    "update_id":659510742,
    "message":{
        "message_id":178,
        "from":{
            "id":110910409,
            "first_name":"S.M_Emamian"
        },
        "chat":{
            "id":-57184742,
            "title":"Vvggg",
            "type":"group"
        },
        "date":1446970836,
        "new_chat_participant":{
            "id":131677747,
            "first_name":"Shadyab",
            "username":"Shadyabbot"
        }
    }

}
```

now, I would like to get `first_name`. how can I get that ?

I tested below code, but it doesn't work :

```
 $json_a = json_decode($content, true);

 $first_name = $json_a->message->from->first_name; //it returns nothing.
```

Comment: `var_dump($json_a);`

Comment: it's ok, but it is an array. You provide `true` to `json_encode`

Answer (score 3):

```
$json_a = json_decode($content, true);
                                ^^^^
```

That `true` forces the output of `json_decode` to be an array, but you are trying to treat it like an object. Remove that argument **or** use array syntax:

```
$first_name = $json_a['message']['from']['first_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

use only `json_decode($content)` remove `true`

try this code :-

```
 $json_a = json_decode($content);
echo $json_a->message->from->first_name;
```

> `True` convert the output of json_decode to be an `array`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $json_a = json_decode($content, true);
>
> $first_name = $json_a->message->from->first_name; //it returns nothing.
> ```

That's because the function returns an associative array, and not an object.

By using `->` you're trying to access object properties of `$json_a`. What you're really looking for is:

```
$json_a["message"]["from"]["first_name"]
```

This way you're accessing the associative array values by their key, and not trying to access object properties.

I hope this helped,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_a = json_decode($content);

 $first_name = $json_a->message->from->first_name;
```

or

```
 $json_a = json_decode($content,true);

 $first_name = $json_a[message][from][first_name];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `true` as the second argument to `json_decode` which tells it to return an associative array rather than an object.

Either remove the second argument (or change it to the default, `false`), or access the fields using array syntax:

```
$first_name = $json['message']['from']['first_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

json_decode() is a php function used to decode **json** into either **php standard object** or an **associative array** dependent upon argument passed to it

When **true** it will return an associative otherwise by default it returns standard PHP object

According to your requirement please try executing following code snippet for retrieving first name from json document.

```
    $json_a = json_decode($content, true);

   $first_name = $json_a['message']['from']['first_name'];
```

For more detailed description regarding parsing json documents in php please refer the documentation in following URL

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php